# Preventing vertical overflow of child in parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need your help. I made a weather app and it looks okay in desktop but when i tested it on my mobile phone, the contents that the white box is holding were going out of bounds vertically. I tried overflow methods and it didnt work so as defining its container height at 100% and 100vh and it didnt work as well? Any solution ideas?

here is the app that i deployed:
https://sleepy-badlands-75629.herokuapp.com/#

here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css "href="../stylesheets/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/weather-icons/2.0.9/css/weather-icons.css">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="appBox">
    <div class="container">
      <header class="text-center">
        <h1>Local Weather App</h1>
      </header>
      <section class="geolocation">
        <h1>Today's weather in your location:</h1>
        <h2><span id="location"></span></h2>
      </section>
      <section class="temperature">
        <h1>
          <span class="tempDisp"></span>
          <a id="fahrenheit" class="selected" href="#">&#8457;</a> |
          <a id="celsius" href="#">&#8451;</a>
        </h1>
      </section>
      <section class="condition">
        <h1><span class="conDisp"></span></h1>
        <div class="highLow col">
          <p>
            <span class="high"></span>&deg;/
            <span class="low"></span>&deg;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="humidity col">
          <p><i class="wi wi-humidity"></i> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="wind col">
          <p>
            <i class="wi wi-small-craft-advisory"></i>
            <span class="direction"></span><span class="speed"></span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="forecast">
        <h1>5 Day Forecast</h1>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800');

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /* overflow:hidden; */
  font-family: raleway;
  text-align: center;
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

.appBox{
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  bottom: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 8px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.container{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: black;
}

a:hover{
  color: purple;
}

.selected{
  color: blue;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events:none;
}


header h1{
  text-align: center;
}

.temperature{
  font-size: 2em;
}

.condition p{
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.col{
  font-size: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  width:20%;
  /* margin: 5px; */
  /* padding: 10px; */
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(250,250,250, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 7px 27px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -2px 7px 27px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: -2px 7px 27px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.forecast{
  width:100%;
  margin: 20px;
}

.forecast h1{
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.fcol{
  display: inline-block;
  width:20%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border: 1px solid white;
}

@media(max-width:700px){
  /* .appBox{
    height: 100vh;
  } */
  .col{
    /* display:block; */
    width: 35%;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `.forecast` class, the `margin: 20px;` is pushing your `forecast` element off center in the smaller width screens. On the larger scale it's not quite as noticeable, but that 20px bump becomes much more noticeable once your real estate shrinks.

I used the developer console to reassign it to `margin: auto;` and it seemed to rectify the problem. Your element should also center fine with this change as it is a nested element.

```
.forecast {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
}
```

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is that the *content* goes out of bounds, why not make the *content* size relative or use css media queries.

You can use `vh` to set the size of the content relative to the height of the viewport.

You can also use something like `@media screen and (max-width: 480px)` to determine when devices are small enough to cause the content to go out of bounds then write new sizes for the content here.